# Extract Specific Parameter value using Regex Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

Given input string as

```
'PARAM_1=TRUE,THRESHOLDLIST=kWh,2000,Gallons,1000,litre,3000,PARAM_2=TRUE,PARAM_3=abc,123,kWh,800,Gallons,500'
```

and unit_param = 'Gallons'
I need to extract value of unit_param (Gallons) which is 1000 using postgresql regex functions.

As of now, I have a function that first extracts value for THRESHOLDLIST which is "kWh,2000,Gallons,1000,litre,3000", then splits and loops over the array to get the value.

Can I get this efficiently using regex.

```
SELECT substring('PARAM_1=TRUE,THRESHOLDLIST=kWh,2000,Gallons,1000,litre,3000,PARAM_2=TRUE,PARAM_3=abc,123,xyz' FROM '%THRESHOLDLIST=#".........#",%' FOR '#')
```

Comment: I assume switching that to a better (parsable) format (e.g. JSON) isn't an option? That would make things a lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substring()` with the target input grouped:

```
substring(myCol, 'THRESHOLDLIST=[^=]*Gallons,([0-9]+)')
```

The expression `[^=]*` means “characters that are not `=`”, so it won’t match Gallons within another parameter.

Comment: the occurrence of Gallon could be in other parameters too. I want to confirm the value is coming from the  THRESHOLDLIST.

Comment: @FurqanShaikh better update your question to say that then, plus update your example to include two occurrences of Gallon to make it clear.

Comment: @furq I’ve updated the regex to only match within THRESHOLDLIST

Answer (score 0):

select
Substring('PARAM_1=TRUE,THRESHOLDLIST=kWh,2000,Gallons,1000,litre,3000,PARAM_2=TRUE,PARAM_3=abc,123,xyz' from 'Gallons,\d*');

returns Gallons,1000